# How to know when an ingestion is complete?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using `azure.kusto.ingest.QueuedIngestClient` to ingest pandas DataFrames into tables via the `ingest_from_dataframe` method, e.g.

```
client = QueuedIngestClient(...)
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
response = client.ingest_from_dataframe(df, ...)
```

`response` is of type `azure.kusto.ingest.base_ingest_client.IngestionResult` and has an attribute `status`. However, it's always `<IngestionStatus.QUEUED: 'QUEUED'>` even after the ingestion finished (checked manually via a query to the DB). So how do I know in my program when an ingestion is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom of https://pypi.org/project/azure-kusto-ingest/ you can see the following links:

- How to install the package.
- Data ingest sample.
- GitHub Repository.

On [Data ingest sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/master/azure-kusto-ingest/tests/sample.py) you can find full examples.

Here is a full working example (just set your cluster URL and your database name) + execution results.
This code was executed against [ADX free cluster](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/freecluster)

**Please note**
Checking your async ingestion status might have a bad impact on your ingestion & cluster performance, especially for high volume ingestion.

On the ADX cluster side:

```
.create table MyTable(id:long, name:string, value:real)
```

The Python code:

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.ingest import IngestionProperties, QueuedIngestClient, ReportLevel 
from azure.kusto.data.data_format import DataFormat
from azure.kusto.ingest.status import KustoIngestStatusQueues
import pandas
import time 
import pprint

cluster = "https://ingest-#.kusto.windows.net/"
database = "MyDatabase"
table = "MyTable"

fields = ["id", "name", "value"]
rows = [[1, "abc", 15.3], [2, "cde", 99.9]]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=fields)

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_interactive_login(cluster)
client = QueuedIngestClient(kcsb)
ingestion_properties = IngestionProperties(database=database, table=table, data_format=DataFormat.CSV, report_level=ReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses)
client.ingest_from_dataframe(df, ingestion_properties=ingestion_properties)


qs = KustoIngestStatusQueues(client)

MAX_BACKOFF = 180

backoff = 1

while True:

    if qs.success.is_empty() and qs.failure.is_empty():
        time.sleep(backoff)
        backoff = min(backoff * 2, MAX_BACKOFF)
        print("No new messages. backing off for {} seconds".format(backoff))
        continue

    backoff = 1

    success_messages = qs.success.pop(10)
    failure_messages = qs.failure.pop(10)

    pprint.pprint(f"SUCCESS : {success_messages}")
    pprint.pprint(f"FAILURE : {failure_messages}")
```

Execution results:

```
No new messages. backing off for 2 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 4 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 8 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 16 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 32 seconds
('SUCCESS : '
 '[SuccessMessage({"OperationId":"7cd42ccf-1ed7-4217-b27c-09f9851c0cec","Database":"MyDatabase","Table":"MyTable","SucceededOn":"2022-11-21T20:43:09.3784058Z","IngestionSourceId":"b1bd0c01-2b22-4378-8bcc-0219331be5a4","RootActivityId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","IngestionSourcePath":"https://#.blob.core.windows.net/#-20221121-ingestdata-e5c334ee145d4b4-0/MyDatabase__MyTable__b1bd0c01-2b22-4378-8bcc-0219331be5a4__df_1939259869456_1669063349_4931c16d-bc90-4cd5-b71a-db64e60835d1.csv.gz"})]')
'FAILURE : []'
No new messages. backing off for 2 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 4 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 8 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 16 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 32 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 64 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 128 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 180 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 180 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 180 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 180 seconds
No new messages. backing off for 180 seconds
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why `.pop(10)` is called with `10` as the argument? Do you know whether this will still work if multiple clients ingest data at the same time? Are the queues isolated between clients or will one client miss messages if I pop messages in another client?

Comment: **(1)** In this example we do just a single ingestion, but theoretically we could have done a series of ingestions and then retrieve the statuses in bulk (E.g., 10 at a time). **(2)** Sure. **(3)** AFAIK you must use the same client to retrieve the ingestion status.

Comment: There's a very important comment in the code you linked to: the report-level of the ingestion properties must be set to `ReportLevel.FailuresAndSuccesses`, otherwise successes will never be recognized.

Comment: @actual_panda, yes, and it also appears in my demo. Check out *ingestion_properties*

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Great example. Two questions: **(1)** How can the ingestion speed be improved, or what determines it? The example takes about 7 minutes before resulting in SUCCESS for `df` consisting of two rows. Note that I am not using a free cluster. Currently `.ingest inline into MyTable` seems to perform better. **(2)** SUCCESS is followed by three successmessages, each with a separate IngestionSourceId. `MyTable` on the database in ADX consists of 3 times the rows in `df`. How can this occur?

Comment: @TheDude **(1)** There is a tradeoff between latency and cluster's/queries' performance . read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batchingpolicy#sealing-a-batch **(2)** No idea what you did there. **P.S.** Please follow SO guidelines and leverage new posts for follow-up questions.